# Getting gui dialog pop-ups (from bash) to stay on top of other windows

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting, kde-plasma, user-interface

I posted this on the [yad list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/yad-common/qu_gEwN17M4), apparently with invisibility enabled (nobody's even viewed it! - usually, the list is very responsive.), so I thought I'd see if any of you have some ideas. It probably applies to any bash script using any gui pop-up utility such as dialog, xdialog, or zenity with the KDE desktop.

In general, I love yad. It blows away zenity and the developer is usually right there to answer questions and fix/enhance things.

Essentially, I have a set of scripts that use pop-up gui dialogs for interaction with the user.

It works great until you click the mouse anywhere else on the KDE desktop while one of the pop-ups is displayed.

Once you do that, all subsequent dialogs "appear" behind everything else and are usually invisible except for in the taskbar and have to be manually selected from there to become visible/active/focused again.

Is there a way to fix this? I assume it's a desktop and not a yad problem.

Thanks,

Joe
kubuntu precise 64-bit (KDE 4.8.5)

---

My [duplex](https://sourceforge.net/projects/duplexpr/) printing system, written in bash, makes multiple calls to yad from within one (possibly nested) script. It works great, but has one major problem.

If the user clicks the mouse anywhere outside a yad dialog while the script is running and displaying something with yad, all subsequent yad dialogs appear behind everything else and are essentially invisible.

The script still shows up in the task manager, so these dialogs can be brought back to the foreground one by one, but it's really counter-intuitive and annoying.

I assume this is a "feature" of KDE and not a bug in yad.
Is there any way to fix/prevent this? I tried adding --on-top to the dialogs, but it didn't help.

When I'm running the script (which may take awhile, or I may want to do something else while a dialog is waiting for input), I can't do anything else for fear of having this problem occur. I can switch to another desktop, but that's dodgy because the next dialog (but only that one) may pop up there and throw the whole thing off.
I'm using the latest yad from the ppa on kubuntu precise.

Comment: You should ask this question on stackoverflow -- it is not Ubuntu specific.

Comment: Have you tried with the KDE window behavior settings ? You could set a KDE window rule to keep a window or group of windows above others.

Comment: @January I'd be fine with someone moving it there. Wouldn't it be cross-posting if I just do it?

Comment: @user26687 I've played with those settings manually on existing windows and by using kstart, but I don't know any way to preset them for a yad pop-up from a script, etc..

Answer (score 2):

The stacking order of windows is controlled by the KDE window manager. When a UI application, like `yad`, creates a window, it may communicate preferred attributes, like "always on top", to the WM. When this does not work for some reason, you may try to call command line utility, for example `wmctrl` that instructs the WM to raise an existing window:

```
wmctrl -a "Yad"
```

Comment: Thanks for replying to an old question! I have two interconnected test scripts: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/54584985/script1 and
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/54584985/script2 I've been trying some variations of what you suggest with no luck. If you don't have yad installed, then some other dialog fork would probably do the same thing. If you or someone else can see what I'm doing wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it. Yad got updated and the windows now stay on top, but still lose the focus.

Comment: I tried `wmctrl -a <window name>` on Solaris with GNOME/Metacity. It works as expected, including getting the keyboard focus. You can list the active window names with `wmctrl -l`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I had the same issue with a zenity dialog poped up from a gedit custom External tool (sh script). Adding the `wmctrl -a "CVS commit"` cmd fixed it.